# The 'header_image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

When I create a new post with an image, everything is fine, but if I edit it, I want to delete the image using the "clear" button, then this error appears, and if I change, then nothing changes, but there are no errors

here is **models.py**
`

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()
    header_image =  models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/", default='#') #new

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])`
```

here is **views.py**
`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Post


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

@property
def image_url(self):
    """
    Return self.photo.url if self.photo is not None,
    'url' exist and has a value, else, return None.
    """
    if self.image:
        return getattr(self.photo, 'url', None)
    return None`
```

**post_base.html**

```
`{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <header>
        <div class="nav-left">
          <h1><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Django blog</a></h1>
            <h2><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/">Admin</a></h2>

        </div>
        <div class="nav-right">
           <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">+ New Blog Post</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Hi {{ user.username }}!</p>
      {% else %}
        <p>You are not logged in.</p>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a><br>
          <p><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/accounts/signup/">Sign up</a></p>
      {% endif %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

**post_detail.html**
`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post-entry">
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
    </div>

    <p><a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}">+ Edit Blog Post</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'post_delete' post.pk %}">+ Delete Blog Post</a></p>
    <img src="{{ post.header_image.url|default_if_none:'#' }}">

    {{ post.body|safe }}
{% endblock content %}`
```

**post_new.html**
`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
{% endblock content %}`
```

**post_edit.html**
`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit post</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>

{% endblock content %}`
```

Comment: Can you try with adding proper default value to image field?

Comment: if I understood you correctly, then you meant it: I changed the '#' in models.py and in views.py to 'fox.jpeg', which I had on my desktop, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

`enctype='multipart/form-data'` means that no characters will be encoded. that is why this type is used while uploading files to server. So multipart/form-data is used when a form requires binary data, like the contents of a file, to be uploaded.

You forgot to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your `post_edit.html` `form` and that's the reason your files aren't sent to Django. Following code should work.

**post_edit.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit post</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```